# How to prove the inequality $|e^{2 \pi i \alpha x} - e^{2 \pi i \alpha y}| \ll \|\alpha(x-y)\|$.

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-sum

How to prove the inequality $|e^{2 \pi i \alpha x} - e^{2 \pi i \alpha y}| \ll \|\alpha(x-y)\|$?

Here $\|\alpha x\|$ is the distance from $\alpha x$ to the nearest integer.

My attempt was to rewrite the LHS of the inequality as $|e^{2 \pi i \alpha(x-y)} -1| = |e^{2 \pi i \alpha \frac{x-y}{2}} - e^{2 \pi i \alpha \frac{y-x}{2}}| = 2|\sin(\pi \alpha (x-y))|$.

But the issue is it seems the opposite inequality is true, since I think one can prove that $\sin(\pi \alpha(x-y)) \gg \|\alpha(x-y)\|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$|\exp^{2 \pi i \alpha x} - \exp^{2\pi i \alpha y} | = |e^{2\pi i \alpha(x-y)}-1|$$

Now check that
$$|e^{2\pi i t} -1| = |e^{2\pi i (t+ m)} -1|$$
if $m$ is an integer and also
$$|e^{2\pi i t} -1|\le 2 \pi |t|$$

Obs: you may be missing a factor of $2\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. In proving the final inequality I tried squaring both sides which yields $2 - 2\cos(2 \pi t) \leq 4 \pi^2 t^2$. The LHS is at most 4, and since we can add integers to $t$ we can see the RHS is greater than 4, and so we are done. Is this correct?

Comment: @trynalearn: For valued functions, the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions) is an inequality, but it's useful. Therefore, $|e^{is}-1| \le |s|$ for $s$ real. It really means that the chord is shorter than the arc.